# Ember.js - Receiving Image From User

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ember.js

In Rails, we can upload images with a form using gems like "paperclip" and "carrierwave", and can then resize them.

I'd like to know how I do the same thing using Rails only for the backend, and Ember.js for the frontend.

How can I receive an image from the user and resize it later? I am using Ember.js + Ruby on Rails?

Comment: As it stands, your question is not specific enough, and answers would likely be too broad or opinionated.  You need to show your own effort and attempts at researching the problem, and then ask a specific question about a specific issue. For help, see “[How to Ask a Good Question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)”.  

A little research will lead you to sites like [Ember Observer](https://emberobserver.com/), which could help you find a solution.

Answer (score 0):

As you build SPA, it means all data should be sent using AJAX. Depending on what browsers you need to support, for AJAX file uploads you use one of following approaches or combination of them:

- [FormData](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/FormData) for actual (fresh) browser versions
- Flash if you need to support IE<11 (I hope you don't)

I made a [blog post](https://blog.gennady.pp.ua/how-to-upload-files-with-ember-js-creating-your-own-uploader/) where I explain how to create a simple uploader for ember.

Also you may use one of [existing uploaders](https://www.google.com.ua/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&rlz=1C1ASUC_enUA645UA645&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=ember%20file%20upload) (look for ember-ready components or wrap some AJAX uploader in component), if set of features they provide is ok for your app.

Backend part should be the same or not very different from classic forms case.

Comment: Thank you for answering.I have been busy last week and this week too.Couldn't respond earlier.Sorry about that.I don't have a chance to test this so may i ask, is this uploads as a part of the form or is it completly different form for just image?

Comment: @MeLearn depends on implementation. 3rd-party components usually send just images(files), often each image in separate async request. My implementation sends all images in one query and may append any data with them (but no support for old IE's). On backend it should look similar as classic form with file fields. In example, in php $_POST (contains data) and $_FILES (contains files) arrays are available

Comment: Thank you so much.I will leave my feedback as soon as i get a chance to try it out. ^.^ thanks.